# Multiply Parameter exclude header row

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

I am trying to **multiply** the **number of owned shares by the current price**, however, I am getting the following error:

```
Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But 'OWNED SHARES' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
```

[image]

| SYMBOL | OWNED SHARES | SHARES PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABML | 100 | 0,5 |
| BABA | 100 | 100 |

Function is

```
={"SHARES PRICE";BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IF(r="",,GOOGLEFINANCE(r, "price")*B:B)))}
```

I tried ***B2:B** but it does not work.

**Excel demo:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e9khzIuRrx9kJHyp8CqS22qX98aLg-50cfd9FCks7fc/edit?usp=sharing

**Note:**
I added **+100 into the Owned Shares Function** just for the demo it loads the data from another sheet in reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
={"SHARES PRICE"; INDEX(IFERROR(BYROW(A2:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)), 
 LAMBDA(x, GOOGLEFINANCE(x, "price")))*B2:B))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again player0 I love your simple solutions! ❤️

Answer (score 3):

**I created a working formula in your table link**

The problem is that by multiplying by `B:B` you multiply the text `Owned Shares`. Here what you'll want to do is to get the values in your `Owned Shares` after the 1st line which will cause an error for every line.

What you need to do is use this :

```
={
"SHARES PRICE";
BYROW(
    F2:F, 
    LAMBDA(
        r, 
        IF(
            r="",
            ,
            IF(
                ROW(r)=1,
                ,
                GOOGLEFINANCE(
                    r, 
                    "price"
                )
                *INDIRECT(
                    CONCAT(
                        "B",
                        ROW(r)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)}
```

Here I replaced our `*B:B` by An `If`checking if it's the first line. If not,
It get the cell value in `B` and at the row of `r` with `Indirect` and multiply it by your `Owned Shares` values.

Comment: Thank you Neo, it works fine! But I will use player0's answer as it's easier to understand :-)